# Whitelist Google Analytics Urls

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

We are using Google Analytics Native SDK for Android and iOS App. We need to whitelist the set of URLs which SDK uses for tracking purpose.

Please can someone provide me the URLs we need to unblock from our network.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following URL:

**port: 80 (http)**

utm.gif">http://www.google-analytics.com/_utm.gif

http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js

**port 443: (https)**

utm.gif">https://ssl.google-analytics.com/_utm.gif

Comment: Thnx for the response,the solution which you gave is for web.I need it for native ios and android sdk.